# Как правильно написать?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно написать?

```
 button_left.style.borderLeft = "1px solid" +gradient[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужен пробел после SOLID

```
button_left.style.borderLeft = "1px solid " +gradient[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй jQuery

```
$("#button_left").css('border-left','1px solid ' + gradient[0]);
```